# Keycloak realm settings does not show up "Duplicate Emails" switch anymore

Tags: keycloak

We've setup a Keycloak server a while ago, added some Active Directory federations and now found out, that some users aren't synced, because they use the same E-Mail address as some others. In our case this is correct, so no easy way to change this.

I remembered a REALM-setting where one could prevent/allow the use of duplicate emails, but could not find it anymore in our REALM. I therefore created a new one, and there it shows up unter REALM-Settings/Login.

Whatever i tried to do, i cannot get this switch back to change the setting to allow duplicate emails. I've checked the database (`select duplicate_emails_allowed from realm where id = 'companyrealm';`) and see that it is set to 'f' (false). Also tried to set it to 't' (true) but this make no difference.

When we create another REALM, the setting is there. Strang, eh? Could it be that the show up of this setting depends on something? We already tried to remove all imported users, disabled the federation provider, even deleted him, but nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think you are missing this switch:

[Keycloak REALM login settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJWGz.png)

It is only show up if the option "Email as username" is set to "OFF". This option itself is only shown if the setting "User registration" is turned "ON". So if the "Email as username" is enalbed ("ON") but the "User registration" was set to "OFF", it will prevent the "Duplicate emails" option to be shown at all. I consider this a bug in Keycloak.

To came out of this situation simply enable "User registration" (even without saving now), then turn off "Email as username" and disable "User registration" again. You will now have the "Duplicate emails" switch available again an can turn it on and off as you like.

Comment: Great job! That finally solved my problem. I can now access the setting again. Somebody should report this to the project.

Comment: It is not a bug