# Keycloak registration throws HTTP 500 for duplicate email

Tags: keycloak, email-validation, internal-server-error, user-registration

I know there's an earlier question with this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742302/keycloak-internal-server-error-when-a-user-tries-to-register-with-an-existing-em), but the OP never reported if the one answer resolved the issue. And since

```
Internal Server Error
```

is about as user-unfriendly as you can get, I would love to change this to something that feels more like *"a message"* than *"an anvil dropped on your foot"*.

I have found [one other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064974/keycloak-realm-settings-does-not-show-up-duplicate-emails-switch-anymore?rq=1) that tangentially relates to this issue (about that disappearing "duplicate emails" switch), but the problem is indeed not about whether or not to allow duplicate emails (or how to revive hidden admin controls) but how a very ordinary issue is communicated to the user - well, like how Keycloak notifies the user when they try and register with an existing username.

We're currently using the Docker version of Keycloak 12.0.4 with some customisations (a custom BCrypt module, some logging changes) running in IBM Cloud, using a Postgresql DB. We also added a custom theme & internationalisation. The same error occurs also when using the default Keycloak theme, though.

Here are our **Login** settings:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a configuration issue, but so deeply hidden that even the Keycloak developer who looked into the ticket I created had glossed over it.

The perpetrator was in menu Configure > Authentication > tab: Flows > choose dropdown: Registration > Profile validation radio button [o REQUIRED | o DISABLED]

This was set to disabled, which in effect prevents the duplicate email check in the registration form that the Realm settings > tab: Login form suggest are active. But then, of course, the database won't like that, with above-mentioned result.

This combination of settings should at least issue a warning, of course. I hope this will be corrected.